# One pair of brackets for each citation

Tags: bibtex, citing, brackets, multiple-citations

#### Question

```tex
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
I cite \cite{a,b}.
I also cite \cite{a,b,c}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
I cite [1, 2]. I also cite [1, 2, 3].
```

But I want

```
I cite [1] and [2]. I also cite [1], [2], and [3].
```

How can I achieve this?

##### Note

Because I'm going to upload it to arXiv, I can't use BibLaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % for arXiv submission it is needed

% save the old meaning
\NewCommandCopy{\latexcite}{\cite}

% proceed to redefine
\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{om}
 {
  \IfValueTF { #1 }
   {% optional argument, only one cite
    \latexcite[#1]{#2}
   }
   {% no optional argument
    \bw_cite_multiple:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \bw_cite_multiple_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \bw_cite_multiple:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \bw_cite_multiple_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {% populate the sequence
    \seq_put_right:Nn \bw_cite_multiple_seq { \latexcite{##1} }   
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \bw_cite_multiple_seq
   {~and\nobreakspace}  % between two items
   {,~}                 % between the first items
   {,~and\nobreakspace} % between last two
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

I cite \cite[p.~1]{a}.

I cite \cite{b}.

I cite \cite{a,b}.

I also cite \cite{a,b , c}.

\begin{thebibliography}{3}

\bibitem{a} First

\bibitem{b} Second

\bibitem{c} Third

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Note that spaces around commas in the list are ignored.

If there is the optional argument only one citation is expected and it's treated as usual. Without the optional argument, the input is split at commas and a sequence is populated, which can be “used” with different separators between items as shown in the comments and the output.

[image]

Note: I used a `thebibliography` environment for simplicity. The code also works with the bibliography built by BibTeX, because the program produces a `thebibliography` environment in the `.bbl` file.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following lines to your preamble.

```
\let\citeorig\cite
\def\cite#1{\citeA#1,\relax,}
\def\citeA#1,{\citeorig{#1}\citeB}
\def\citeB#1,{\ifx\relax#1\let\tmp\relax\else\def\tmp{\citeC{#1}}\fi\tmp}
\def\citeC#1#2,{\ifx\relax#2\def\tmp{ and \citeorig{#1}}\else\def\tmp{, \citeorig{#1},\citeD{#2}}\fi\tmp}
\def\citeD#1#2,{\ifx\relax#2\def\tmp{ and \citeorig{#1}}\else\def\tmp{ \citeorig{#1},\citeD{#2}}\fi\tmp}
```

[image]

This output is the result of running

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

on the file `test.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\let\citeorig\cite
\def\cite#1{\citeA#1,\relax,}
\def\citeA#1,{\citeorig{#1}\citeB}
\def\citeB#1,{\ifx\relax#1\let\tmp\relax\else\def\tmp{\citeC{#1}}\fi\tmp}
\def\citeC#1#2,{\ifx\relax#2\def\tmp{ and \citeorig{#1}}\else\def\tmp{, \citeorig{#1},\citeD{#2}}\fi\tmp}
\def\citeD#1#2,{\ifx\relax#2\def\tmp{ and \citeorig{#1}}\else\def\tmp{ \citeorig{#1},\citeD{#2}}\fi\tmp}
\begin{document}
I cite \cite{a,b}.
I also cite \cite{a,b,c}.
And I cite \cite{a,b,c,d}.
And even \cite{a,b,c,d,e}.
And again \cite{a}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

and the file `ref.bib` containing

```
@Misc{a,
  key = {a},
  title = {The A Report},
}
@Misc{b,
  key = {b},
  title = {The B Report},
}
@Misc{c,
  key = {c},
  title = {The C Report},
}
@Misc{d,
  key = {d},
  title = {The D Report},
}
@Misc{e,
  key = {e},
  title = {The E Report},
}
```